# cannot find entry symbol nable-stdcall-fixup

Tags: qt5, warning

Пишу программу в Qt5. Все было нормально, тут захожу, запускаю проект (даже новый создавал) и тут ошибка

> cannot find entry symbol nable-stdcall-fixup; defaulting to 00401000

Код не буду скидывать т.к это пустой проект созданный минуту назад

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13251752/4711135

Comment: Спасибо огромное!